# Spring Boot marshall Xml from RestTemplate without RootElement

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, resttemplate

I am using a RestTemplate like this:

```
return this.getForEntity(baseUrl, BasicResponse.class, parameters);
```

This is the BasicResponse class:

```
public class BasicResponse {

private String status;
private String statusMsg;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getStatusMsg() {
    return statusMsg;
}

public void setStatusMsg(String statusMsg) {
    this.statusMsg = statusMsg;
}
```

}

No exceptions are thrown but the fields in the returned ResponseEntity body are 'null'. I think it's because the element does not have a valid XML structure (as in no root element). I do not have control over the parsed XML. How can I map my object?

Comment: XML that does not have a root element is not XML.  It is something that pretends to be XML, but which fails.

Answer (score 0):

Since the XML is not valid,
I believe that you will not be able to use `RestTemplate.getForEntity`
to get a `BasicResponse` object.

Try this:

```
private static final String VALUE_END_TAG = "</blammy>";
private static final String VALUE_START_TAG = "<blammy>";

private XmlMapper xmlMapper; // initialize this correctly, somewhere off page.

method stuff
{
  final String actualResponse;
  final StringBuilder correctedResponse = new StringBuilder();
  final BasicResponse returnValue;

  actualResponse = restTemplate.getForEntity(baseUrl, BasicResponse.class, parameters);

  correctedResponse.append(VALUE_START_TAG);
  correctedResponse.append(actualResponse);
  correctedResponse.append(VALUE_END_TAG);

  returnValue = xmlMapper.readValue(correctedResponse.toString(), BasicResponse.class);

  return returnValue;
}
```

Use some reasonable value as the element name in the start and end tags,
perhaps "" and "".

Consider using some Jackson annotations,
for example `@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "blammy")`
(this local name matches my example).